# rest extension will not transform json

Tags: json, rest, xslt, marklogic

I have a MarkLogic Rest extension which needs to transform JSON into OBI objects. For starters I created an XML input and created transforms for it, therse work.

Now the real data is slightly different and in JSON, so I need to transform the JSON to XML. I have had an example xsl transform that I cannot seem to get to work...

The JSON doc that I want to load via the rest extension:

```
{
    "wifi_raw": [
        {
            "id": "4354279",
            "hostname": "rb-0046",
            "mac": "00:0C:43:00:08:F4",
            "firstseen": "2015-08-12 13:54:50",
            "lastseen": "2015-08-12 13:54:50",
            "rssi": "-1",
            "packets": "1",
            "bssid": "24:A4:3C:53:19:62",
            "probes": "",
            "processed": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "4354257",
            "hostname": "rb-0046",
            "mac": "00:0E:58:BC:E9:03",
            "firstseen": "2015-08-12 13:48:45",
            "lastseen": "2015-08-12 13:52:10",
            "rssi": "-58",
            "packets": "3",
            "bssid": "B8:E9:37:17:DA:EF",
            "probes": "sonos_hbbzdjrspta2htbcqeb0gcjouc",
            "processed": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "4354273",
            "hostname": "rb-0046",
            "mac": "00:0E:58:BC:E9:03",
            "firstseen": "2015-08-12 13:48:45",
            "lastseen": "2015-08-12 13:54:32",
            "rssi": "-61",
            "packets": "4",
            "bssid": "B8:E9:37:17:DA:EF",
            "probes": "sonos_hbbzdjrspta2htbcqeb0gcjouc",
            "processed": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

On ingest I want to transform this to OBI objects which are all defined and work for the equivalent XML input doc...

If I do

> json:transform-from-json($source)

In the ingest extension the JSON transforms to this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<json xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic" type="object">
  <wifi__raw type="array">
    <json type="object">
      <id type="string">4354279</id>
      <hostname type="string">rb-0046</hostname>
      <mac type="string">00:0C:43:00:08:F4</mac>
      <firstseen type="string">2015-08-12 13:54:50</firstseen>
      <lastseen type="string">2015-08-12 13:54:50</lastseen>
      <rssi type="string">-1</rssi>
      <packets type="string">1</packets>
      <bssid type="string">24:A4:3C:53:19:62</bssid>
      <probes type="string"/>
      <processed type="string">0</processed>
    </json>
    <json type="object">
      <id type="string">4354257</id>
      <hostname type="string">rb-0046</hostname>
      <mac type="string">00:0E:58:BC:E9:03</mac>
      <firstseen type="string">2015-08-12 13:48:45</firstseen>
      <lastseen type="string">2015-08-12 13:52:10</lastseen>
      <rssi type="string">-58</rssi>
      <packets type="string">3</packets>
      <bssid type="string">B8:E9:37:17:DA:EF</bssid>
      <probes type="string">sonos_hbbzdjrspta2htbcqeb0gcjouc</probes>
      <processed type="string">0</processed>
    </json>
    <json type="object">
      <id type="string">4354273</id>
      <hostname type="string">rb-0046</hostname>
      <mac type="string">00:0E:58:BC:E9:03</mac>
      <firstseen type="string">2015-08-12 13:48:45</firstseen>
      <lastseen type="string">2015-08-12 13:54:32</lastseen>
      <rssi type="string">-61</rssi>
      <packets type="string">4</packets>
      <bssid type="string">B8:E9:37:17:DA:EF</bssid>
      <probes type="string">sonos_hbbzdjrspta2htbcqeb0gcjouc</probes>
      <processed type="string">0</processed>
    </json>
  </wifi__raw>
</json>
```

My minimum xsl transform now is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

  xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp"
  xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
  xmlns:basic="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic"
  xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"

  xmlns:obj="http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/object"

  extension-element-prefixes="xdmp">

  <xdmp:import-module namespace="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" href="/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy"/>

  <xsl:param name="params" as="map:map"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ingest-time" select="(map:get($params, 'ingest-time'), 'false')[1] = 'true'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/text()[empty(../*)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json:transform-from-json(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="basic:json">
    <results>
      <objects>
        <!-- test -->
        <xsl:text>example</xsl:text>
      </objects>

      <links>
        <!-- links go here-->
        <xsl:text>example</xsl:text>
      </links>
    </results>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get NO results back from the

```
let $result := eput:apply-document-transform(fn:concat($dataset, '-transform'), $params, $context, $source)/element()
```

In the ingest extension.

As I understood this the match "match="/text()[empty(../*)]">" would be true for the JSON document node, so the same transform-from-json would generate the XML version of the original JSON doc also posted here above so I could at least find the root node with "match="basic:json""

What am I missing here?

EDIT WORKING SOLUTION

This is basically what worked. First we made sure the new JSON object-node() is matched, then you have to be really carefull with the matching XSL templates. I had two templates matched for "basic:json" witch resulted in only the last to be executed...

Now the root is matched with

```
<xsl:template match="/basic:json">
```

And the one inside the array is matched with ANY child of wifi__raw like

```
<xsl:template match="basic:wifi__raw/*">
```

The complete XSL now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

  xmlns:xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp"
  xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
  xmlns:basic="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic"
  xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map"

  xmlns:obj="http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/object"

  extension-element-prefixes="xdmp">

  <xdmp:import-module namespace="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" href="/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy"/>

  <xsl:param name="params" as="map:map"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ingest-time" select="(map:get($params, 'ingest-time'), 'false')[1] = 'true'"/>

  <!-- voor MarkLogic 7 -->
  <xsl:template match="/text()[empty(../*)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json:transform-from-json(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- voor MarkLogic 8 -->
  <xsl:template match="/node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json:transform-from-json(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/basic:json">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="basic:wifi__raw"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="basic:wifi__raw">
    <xsl:variable name="objects" as="element()*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <results>
      <objects>
        <xsl:sequence select="$objects" />
      </objects>

    </results>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="basic:wifi__raw/*">
    <foundId>
      <xsl:value-of select="basic:id" />
    </foundId>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by MarkLogic 8 handling JSON datatype differently from MarkLogic 7 and before. In MarkLogic 8, JSON data gets processed into `object-node()` data, not into `text()`. Unfortunately, you cannot explicitly test for `object-node()` in XSLT, but there are a few ways to work around that. Change the match for `text()` like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/node()[not(self::*)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="json:transform-from-json(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This should work in both MarkLogic 7 and 8.

HTH!

Comment: hmmm: adding this template gets me to "errorResponse":{"statusCode":500, "status":"Internal Server Error", "messageCode":"INTERNAL ERROR", "message":"XSLT-BADPATTERN: (err:XTSE0340) Invalid pattern: fn:doc(\"/marklogic.rest.transform/csjson-transform/assets/transform.xsl\")/*:stylesheet/*:template[1]/@match (XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Lpar_, expecting $end)

Comment: Sorry, forgot that XSLT syntax is more strict than XQuery syntax in MarkLogic. I changed my answer with something that does work..

Comment: That is a different issue.. ;-)